# How to manipulate a Dom to select only text content inside tags？

Tags: javascript, html

How do I select the text inside tags excluding the content of other tags. For example:

```
<div id='id'>text that I want to select<p>text that I don't want</p></div>
```

In this case, how do I use something like this, to get the plain text?

```
document.getElementByID('id').innerText
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, you loop through the *text nodes* in the element, ignoring the non-text nodes (which includes child elements):

```js
var element = document.getElementById("id");
var text = "";
for (var child = element.firstChild;
     child;
     child = child.nextSibling) {
  if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    text += child.nodeValue;
  }
}

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id='id'>text that I want to select<p>text that I don't want</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XPATH in order to select your element's own text

```js
var result = document.evaluate( "//div[@id='id']/text()", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null );

alert(result.stringValue)
```

```html
<div id='id'>
  text that I want to select
  <p>text that I don't want</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That will miss out any text after the `p` element in the `div`.

Answer (score -1):

somthing like that can do

```js
 var t =
(document.getElementById("id") ).childNodes

for (let index = 0; index < t.length; index++) {
    const element = t[index];

   
    
    if( element.tagName === undefined ){  document.getElementById("out").append(element.cloneNode()) ;}

}
```

```html
<div id='id'>text that I want to select<p>text that I don't want</p></div>

<div id="out" style="color:blue"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.clear()

function noChildTextContent(el) {
  var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
  var childNodes = clone.childNodes;
  var ret = "";
  for (let childNode in childNodes) {
    if (childNodes.hasOwnProperty(childNode)) {
      if (childNodes[childNode].nodeType == 3) {
        ret += ` ${childNodes[childNode].textContent}`
      }
    }
  }
  return ret.trim();
}
console.log(noChildTextContent(document.getElementById('id')))
```

```html
<div id='id'>text that I want to select<p>text that I don't want</p>Want it again</div>
```